# How do you change the images emacs uses as file/folder indicators

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to change icons Emacs uses to indicate folders and files (in dirtree). See the following image for an example:

[Example of how I want the icons to look http://cezar.halmagean.ro/snaps/dirtree.png](http://cezar.halmagean.ro/snaps/dirtree.png)

Comment: what dirtree library are you using?  that doesn't seem to be built into emacs

Comment: https://github.com/zkim/emacs-dirtree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't see the images you cite, to use ASCII rather than folder icons - open dirtree.el and replace 'folder' with 'ascii'

```
(define-derived-mode dirtree-mode tree-mode "Dir-Tree"
  "A mode to display tree of directory"
  (tree-widget-set-theme "folder"))
```

like so:

```
(define-derived-mode dirtree-mode tree-mode "Dir-Tree"
  "A mode to display tree of directory"
  (tree-widget-set-theme "ascii"))
```

See also: http://emhacks.sourceforge.net/tw-shots.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll wan to customize `tree-widget-theme` or fiddle with some of the `tree-widget-themes-*` variables, and maybe create your own theme for it (a theme for it is just a directory with files such as "open.png", "leaf.png", ...